# output within compiler and from exe file differs

Tags: c++

i am using turbo c++. when i run the following code from compiler i get different answer at marked point in function result(int) then what i get from running .exe file created.

```
#include<fstream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<iomanip.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dos.h>

ifstream  fil;
int pos[50];
char date[11];

void exitt(int times = 0)
{
    cout << endl << endl << "     Enter 0 to exit." << endl;
    if (times == 0)
        cout << "     Enter L to return to last screen." << endl;
}
void options();
void companychoose();
void companyscreen(int);
void write(int ch, int pos = 0)                      //add a check for duplicacy
{
    ofstream fout;
    clrscr();
    if (ch == 1)
    {
        fout.open("database.dat", ios::binary | ios::app | ios::ate);
        char companyname[20], temp;
        exitt();
        cout << "     Enter Company name: ";
        gets(companyname);
        if (strcmp(companyname, "0") == 0)
            exit(0);
        else if (strcmp(companyname, "l") == 0)
            options();
        for (int i = 19; i>0; i--)
            companyname[i] = companyname[i - 1];
        companyname[0] = '%';
        fout << endl;
        fout << companyname;
        fout.close();
        cout << "     Add data now?(y/n)" << endl;
    askagain:
        cin >> temp;
        switch (temp)
        {
        case 'y':
            fil.close();
            write(2);
            break;
        case 'n':
            options();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "    Invalid input" << endl;
            goto askagain;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void result(int ch)
{
    int high[4], low[4], end, i = 0, enough = 0, temp = 0;
    char check[20];
    fil.open("database.dat", ios::binary);
    fil.seekg(pos[ch], ios::beg);
    fil >> check;
    cout << endl;
    if (check[0] == '%')
    {
        cout << "    Not Enough Data!!!" << endl;
        fil.close();
        return;
    }
    while (!fil.eof())
    {
        if (i == 3)
        {
            i = 0;
            enough = 1;
        }
        fil >> high[i] >> low[i] >> end >> check;
        if (check[0] == '%')
            break;
        i++;
    }
    low[i] = 0;
    temp = low[0];
    if (enough == 0)
        cout << "    Not Enough Data!!!" << endl;
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            if (low[i]<low[i + 1])
                temp = low[i + 1];
        }
        if (temp>end)
            cout << "     Stock Running Low!!";
        else if (temp = end)
            cout << "     Stock Is Stable";
        else
            cout << "     Stock is HIGH!!";
        cout << "  " << end - temp << endl << endl << endl;
    }
    fil.close();
}

int read(int ch, int find = 0)
{
    clrscr();
    result(ch);
    fil.open("database.dat", ios::binary);
    fil.seekg(pos[ch], ios::beg);
    char entry[20];
    fil >> entry;
    cout << setw(20) << "Date" << setw(10) << "High" << setw(10) << "Low" << setw(10) << "Close" << endl;
    while (entry[0] != '%')
    {
        if (find == 1)
        {
            if (strcmp(entry, date))
                return(fil.tellg() - 11);
            else
                continue;
        }
        cout << setw(20) << entry;
        fil >> entry;
        cout << setw(10) << entry;
        fil >> entry;
        cout << setw(10) << entry;
        fil >> entry;
        cout << setw(10) << entry << endl;
        fil >> entry;
        delay(500);
    }
    fil.close();
    getch();
    clrscr();
    companyscreen(ch);
}

void edit(int ch)
{
    cout << "Enter date of data to be edited";
    gets(date);
    write(2, read(ch, 1));
}

void companyscreen(int ch)
{
    int ch1;
askagain:
    result(ch);
    cout << "    1. Add Data" << endl;
    cout << "    2. Show history" << endl;
    cout << "    3. Edit Data" << endl;
    exitt();
    ch1 = getch() - 48;
    if (ch1 == 1)
        write(2);
    else if (ch1 == 2)
        read(ch);
    else if (ch1 == 3)
    {
        read(ch);
        edit(ch);
    }
    else if (ch1 == 0)
    {
        cout << "   exiting!!" << endl;
        exit(500);
    }
    else if (ch1 == 60)
        companychoose();
    else
    {
        cout << "     Invalid option chosen" << endl;
        getch();
        clrscr();
        goto askagain;
    }
}

void companychoose()
{
    char name[20];
    int i, ch;
    clrscr();
    fil.open("database.dat", ios::binary);
askagain:
    fil.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    cout << "     Choose Company:";
    cout << endl;
    i = 1;
    while (!fil.eof())
    {
        fil >> name;
        if (name[0] == '%')
        {
            name[0] = ' ';
            pos[i] = fil.tellg();
            cout << setw(10) << i << "." << name << endl;
            i++;
        }
    }
    fil.close();
    exitt();
    ch = getch() - 48;
    if (ch == 0)
        exit(0);
    else if (ch == 60)
        options();
    else if (ch>i)
    {
        cout << "Invalid choice" << endl;
        getch();
        clrscr();
        goto askagain;
    }
    clrscr();
    companyscreen(ch);
}

void options()
{
    int ch;
    clrscr();
askagain:
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "       1. Add company" << endl;
    cout << "       2. Choose company" << endl;
    exitt(1);
    ch = getch() - 48;
    if (ch == 1)
        write(1);
    else if (ch == 2)
        companychoose();
    else if (ch == 0)
    {
        cout << setw(10) << "      Exiting!!";
        exit(500);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << setw(10) << "      Invalid choice chosen" << endl;
        getch();
        clrscr();
        goto askagain;
    }
}

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    textbackground(MAGENTA);
    textcolor(WHITE);
    clrscr();
    options();
    getch();
}
```

pls note that program is yet not fully complete so some features dont work.

i don't know how to include dat file data nor screenshot here.

i don't use visual c++ cause my pc is slow.
i don't use codeblocks cause i dont know how to use it. above code give hundreds of error even after adding "using namespace std;"

pls help me solve it. if you need anything else then ask me. thanks

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: oh goto, so we meet again

Comment: Turbo C++ is very old. If your computer is slow you should try `gcc` with console programming instead.

Comment: *"i am using turbo c++"* - Stop right there. Turbo C++ belongs in a museum. It is no longer developed or maintained. Download one of the free, modern compilers for your system.

Comment: Obsolete headers, obsolete services, obsolete behaviour. Please don't learn C++ using Turbo C++, you would learn wrong C++.

Comment: Use a better compiler. E.g. the recently released [GCC 5.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) available since mid july 2015, and free software, and quite C++11 & C++14 standard conforming.

Answer (score 1):

> I get different answer (…) in function result(int) then what I get from running .exe file created.

When you execute your program from the [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) a different [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is used so different files are seemingly present/missing. Usually the working directory is configurable.

By the way, the `goto` is not needed. Really, [it is not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_program_theorem).

Comment: I have only studied c++ in my high school as fifth subject so I can't understand what you said much.  The result from compiler is right one and from exe is wrong.  I am going to use exe for showing to someone so I need it give correct result.   So tell me how to solve this.

Comment: And which goto are you  talking about?